# AVPlayer.currentTime() returns zero

Tags: swift, swiftui, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

**Situation**

I want to implement a AVPlayer with controls. This worked quit well for me:

```
struct AVPlayerView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    var videoURL: URL
    var position: Int64
    
    private var player: AVPlayer {
        return AVPlayer(url: videoURL)
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ playerController: AVPlayerViewController, context: Context) {
        print("updateUIView!")
    }
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> AVPlayerViewController {
        let playerController = AVPlayerViewController()
        playerController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        playerController.player = player
        playerController.player?.seek(to: CMTimeMake(value: 1320, timescale: 1))
        playerController.player?.play()
        return playerController
    }
}
```

In view:

```
VPlayerView(videoURL: URL(string: videoURL)!, position: startPosition).transition(.move(edge: .bottom)).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
```

I also need to get the current time from the AVPlayer when it disappear.
I don't seem to understand how it works at all...
Every time I try to get the `currentTime()` it returns `0`.

I try it in two ways, first instantiate the AVPlayerView as var and to define the player variable as none-private.
The second way, was to define a @State variable and to @Bind it to the struct. On this way, I hoped to trigger the `updateUIViewController` but no luck.
(Got this from here --> https://stackoverflow.com/a/58614780/15797011)

**Questions**

1. How can I get the `currentTime()` from this construction?
2. How can I trigger the `updateUIViewController`?

Comment: `updateUIViewController` gets called whenever the POD (plain old data) inputs to `AVPlayerView` change

Comment: Hi @jnpdx thx for your fast response.

When I define "@State var vpos: Double = 0.0" on the ContentView, where the Player will be displayed, and also define "@Binding var vpos: Double" on the player struct, then the "updateUIViewController" should be triggered, when I change the value of this state?

Comment: Yes. Doesn't need to be a `Binding`, even -- just a plain parameter will work.

Comment: I'm sry to bother you again. Is it possible to add the observer for "AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime" when using structs instead of class?

Comment: Yes. Look at `onReceive:`https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/onreceive(_:perform:)

Comment: Or, if you want to do it inside your `UIViewControllerRepresentable`, use a `Coordinator`

Comment: Thank you again, both solutions works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the Solution, thx to: [jnpdx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/560942/jnpdx?tab=profile)

> 1. How can I get the currentTime() from this construction?

If you are able to call the `currentTime()` from the current item, then it would work. My fault was, I was calling this on the wrong "level".
Add it to the `updateUIViewController` function.

```
func updateUIViewController(_ playerController: AVPlayerViewController, context: Context) {
        print("Current time in sec: \(playerController.player?.currentTime().seconds)")
}
```

> 2. How can I trigger the updateUIViewController?

Thx to [jnpdx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/560942/jnpdx?tab=profile), I try it in another way:
Set the state in the view where the AVPlayer will be displayed:

```
struct PlayerModal: View {
    @State var videoPos: Double = 0.0
    
    var body: some View {
        AVPlayerView(videoURL: URL(string: videoURL)!, position: startPosition, videoPos: videoPos)
    }
}

struct AVPlayerView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    var videoURL: URL
    var position: Int64
    var videoPos: Double
    
    private var player: AVPlayer {
        return AVPlayer(url: videoURL)
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ playerController: AVPlayerViewController, context: Context) {
        print("Current time in sec: \(playerController.player?.currentTime().seconds)")
    }
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> AVPlayerViewController {
        let playerController = AVPlayerViewController()
        playerController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        playerController.player = player
        playerController.player?.seek(to: CMTimeMake(value: 1320, timescale: 1))
        playerController.player?.play()
        return playerController
    }
}
```

And before [jnpdx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/560942/jnpdx?tab=profile) gave me the [hint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76365985/avplayer-currenttime-returns-zero#comment134661029_76365985), I was playing around with `@Binding` on the `AVPlayerView`. This doesn't work. (hope someone can explain me, why...)